# specifying random effects in mixed effect model when each observation can have a subset of levels from a category (as opposed to exactly 1)

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

The problem is the following: I have data from several basketball games. Each row of data is 5 players and the number of points their team scored during the game. My response variable would be the number of points scored. How would I model players as random effects here? If there were only one player per game, I'd simply use a random effect and be done. I'm not sure how to deal with the simultaneous presence of multiple players (from the same population) for a given game.

Comment: It sounds like students and classes are crossed and both are nested within schools. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes, I think it's fine to assume that although I'm not sure it's relevant (unless I'm misunderstanding). I'm curious about how I deal with the fact that it's 8 classes per day as opposed to 1. And remember, my target of interest is on a day level.

Comment: Nesting and crossing of random factors are not assumptions, they are properties of the experimental design. The experimental design, and the coding of the data, dictates how the random effects are specified. What is your response variable ? Do all students take all 8 classes, or just 8 from a larger population of classes ?   I don't fully understand the experimental design here.  Please can you explain the design, and also let us know what your research question is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've edited my original question above with the actual problem I'm trying to solve. I thought the schools/students approach would be easier from an explanation standpoint but is definitely making things more confusing! Thanks for bearing with me. To answer your q, these players come from a larger population of players (call it, the league). And there is only one random effect (player), so no crossing I believe. Thanks!

Comment: OK so that's completely different from the original question !  Each measurement relates to a match played by 5 players. The response is the points scored.   What is the size of the player population ?  Are there any other variables ? What is your research question ?

Comment: The population size of players is around 600-700. The one other variable (which is my variable of interest), is the amount of travel time it took for the group of players to arrive to the location of the game. It's worth noting that each player has the same travel time since they are on the same team. My ultimate research question would be to quantify how travel time (on airplane, bus etc) might affect points scored. I'd like to be able to adjust for the 5 players while doing this which is why I'm curious about including these random effects. Thanks!